# KnockoutJS data-binding with UL LI

Tags: knockout.js

I have a text box and a button, if I enter some text in the text box and click on the button, a UL LI section below the text box will be added with the new item. I want to set databinding for the UL Li so that I can collect all items while submitting the form.

What is the approach I need to take while implementing something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example #2 from the following knockoutjs.com [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) page sounds very close to what you are trying to achieve. With some minor modifications it could meet your needs.